# Here Maps for Javascript, custom styling

Tags: javascript, here-api, styling

I would like to ask about few topics, that we are trying to solve. We are using a HERE Maps API for Javascript and we are struggling with some issues. We are trying to make a “map configurator” which providing own styling of map. We did a little progress with own .yaml files and we are able to define and load our own styles, but we are facing some issues related to Traffic services and Routing. Not with the functionalities, but in term of styling.

**TRAFFIC FLOW**

First is Traffic layer. We are trying to add a live traffic view and we successfully did it. Only problem we are facing is with the layers. Because if we turn on the traffic feature. We are able to see traffic flows, but only option is "on map" in meaning of “also on labels” which results in traffic flow overlaying the labels. The second option how can we display traffic flows is “under the map” which results in quite well behaviour, but in some cases we would need to somehow make the traffic flow wider, but we don’t know how to figure it out.

How we adding flowtiles:

```
var mapTiler = platform.getMapTileService({ type: 'traffic' }),
tileLayer = mapTiler.createTileLayer('flowtile', 'normal.day', 512, 'png', { min_traffic_congestion: 'heavy' });

map.addLayer(tileLayer, 0.7); OR map.addLayer(tileLayer);
```

So, the questions are: is it possible to somehow make the trafficflow between the map and labels? OR is it possible to make the traffic tile wider?

**ROUTING**

We are facing issue also with routing service, we are adding a polyline object and trying to draw a routing shape. We are successful, but the problem is same as it is with TRAFFIC FLOW. The routing shape is over the labels and we don't know how to prioritize the labels in style.

Next problem with routing is fact, that we would like to draw a shape of navigation arrow in maneuvers as it is in Android SDK, which we discovered that is possible to implemented, but we didn’t saw the option in Javascript API. Is it possible to make it look like as it is in Android SDK or at least somehow make it look similar to it.

We are currently getting information about maneuvers. But this operating only with polyline, which providing as part of line where maneuver is, but we are not able to draw it like it is in Android SDK.

So, the questions: how to prioritize the labels as it is from problem with trafficflows? And is it possible to draw a maneuver arrows as it is in Android SDK?

**MAP STYLE**

Last little problem is in map styling. We are not able to align place label(city, borough) we are trying to center it, but unsuccessfully. And is it possible to influence frequency of displayed labels? We assume that is needed to add some parameter to `skeleton.yaml`.

Comment: I can see you had reach out to support@here.com regarding the same query, and I hope I got it resolved for you.